# Sum of values in each column in a table in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

Can we show the total sum value of a particular column at the bottom of the same column in sapui5.
Here i'm using sap ui table.

Thanks,
Sathish

Comment: So far I only saw a sum value feature implemented in `sap.m.Table` as described here: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3610443

Answer (score 3):

### If you are using `sap.ui.table.Table`

You can use different controls like(grid/layouts) to align as per requirement.

```
//Create an instance of the table control
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
    title: "Table Example",
    //other attributes
      footer: new sap.ui.commons.Label({
         text:"1234"
       })
});
```

---

### If you are using `sap.m` libraries:(RECOMMENDED)

Adding `footer` property will do that. footer is one of the aggregation.

**aggregation:** `footer`

**cardinality** : `0..1`

**type**: `sap.ui.core.Control`

**description**: Control to be displayed in the column footer.

Sample code: (use object number instead of Label to differentiate number and currency)

```
new sap.m.Column({
    //hAlign: "Right", use if required
    header: new sap.m.Label({
        text: "Amount"
    }),
    footer: new sap.m.ObjectNumber({
        number: "{Total}",
        unit: "{CurrencyCode}",
        state: "Warning"
    })
});
```

Comment: Good idea but as mentioned in his question he is using `sap.ui.table.Table`

Comment: @TimGerlach I have updated the answer accordingly. thanks for the update

Answer (score 2):

I got a very nice solution with `sap.ui.table.Table`.

Actually adding a footer was not effective because it display the control under the whole table. So What I did is playing with the [multiLabels aggregation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Column/aggregations).

And here I got the Sum displayed under the headline directly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have come across similar issue, I have through lot of searches and came up with a solution for my scenario.

I have used Last Record as Total for all records and property `fixedBottomRowCount="1"`.

Other Possible Solutions:

1. Use Analaytical ALV, which has Total option
2. Footer available at each column. I found this [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3610443), but have not verified the solution.